# Does Twilio Notify support pushes to Apple’s PassKit?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, twilio, passkit

I’m trying to send push notifications using a Pass type ID certificate via Twilio Notify.  ***This is different than sending to an iOS App***.

I’m able to do this from my own server, but I’m receiving an “invalid APNS credentials” error with Twilio...

Amazon Web Service's SNS also doesn't support this particular interface with APNS, so I was hoping Twilio would ... does anyone know the official answer? I can’t find anything in Twilio documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of asking, the answer was "no".

Twilio's customer service was excellent and added PassKit support as a result of a help ticket, so the answer is now "yes".